# What's the best way to tune MTU given different performance against different sites?

Tags: vpn, mtu

I'm running a Wireguard VPN that seems to be handling differences in MTU poorly. Interacting with the Wireguard server from a Mac running 1500 MTU, VPN performance looks something like the following:

- `curl ifconfig.me` -> normal
- `ssh some-machine` -> normal
- google search -> normal
- most sites -> normal
- some sites (e.g., Stack Overflow) -> unusable

I've tried tuning the Wireguard server MTU up to 1500. But, that hasn't made a difference. Should I tune my laptop down?

Comment: For a cable modem, MTU does not need to be set and makes no difference. For a DSL (ADSL) modem, and VPN, try 1492 and see if that works.

Comment: @John On the client or the server?

Comment: I usually did that on the router so that any attached device could take advantage of the setting. Modern gear does not benefit much, however.

Comment: What do you mean by "a Mac running 1500 MTU"? The MTU isn't set for the host, it's set for each interface – are you talking about the Mac's Wi-Fi interface or the WireGuard tunnel interface? Where's the WireGuard client, is it the Mac itself or is it your router?

Comment: @user1686 The WireGuard client is on the Mac itself. Yes, I'm talking about en0 on my Mac.